# how do I search twitter for posts by verified accounts only?

Tags: twitter

Is this possible via the API? Is there already a website that does this?

Comment: No, haven't looked in a while. You?

Comment: have started the process, will post back if I find anything. Looking over the docs though I do see is_verified returned in some of the calls

Comment: Realfun's answer below allows you to search for verified users via the API. I just tried it. Just add "filter:verified" at the end of the search string and the search results will give you a list of only verified accounts.

Comment: The [docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query) suggest that you can use the conjunction `is:verified` in your query string, but I've found it not to work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add "filter:verified" to the search query should work.

From: http://socialmeditation.wordpress.com/2013/04/30/filter-twitter-searches-by-verified-users/

Comment: This is an old answer, but that throws an error now. :/

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought...

I'd imagine that you can make a call to any user account and have it return all its followers, right? If this is true, then all you need to do is check against Twitter's Verified account found here: https://twitter.com/verified.

Answer (score 1):

[DataSift](http://www.datasift.com) allows you to do this. It's Twitter's official partner for advanced searches.

Comment: DataSift is a major social media data provider, you can search verified accounts using Twitter's API without dishing out thousands on this. Unless someone needs an archive of historical tweets

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in using [DataSift](http://datasift.com) for this, here is an example live stream of Tweets from all verified Twitter users - http://datasift.com/stream/22288/tweets-from-verified-users

Answer (score 0):

It seems that filter:verified is not working anymore after the Twitter Blue update. Anything after Jun 24 is not appearing in the results.