# How to pull the list of celebrities via Twitter API?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

How can I pull the list of celebrities , and different categories through the Twitter API ?? Like on this website http://www.twellow.com/categories/entertainment  ... It shows lists of entertainers on thw Twitter API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I search twitter for posts by verified accounts only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268193/how-do-i-search-twitter-for-posts-by-verified-accounts-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That site's categories appear to rely primarily on users listing themselves. Twitter does not natively expose categories such as "celebrities" or "entertainers".