# How to pull the list of verified accounts via Twitter API?

Tags: php, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do I search twitter for posts by verified accounts only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268193/how-do-i-search-twitter-for-posts-by-verified-accounts-only)

How can I pull the list of celebrities on Twitter via the Twitter API?

It looks like there's a way to do it through the API, but when I go to the documentation, I do not find it.

Here is an example of a website with all the entertainers:

```
http://www.twellow.com/categories/entertainment
```

I am wondering how they did it.

Comment: Where you managed to find a solution for that thread?

Answer (score -2):

You have to use there api for do this here is the link

> https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

You can call query like this where `screen_name` is the name of the celebrity that you want and `count` for how much tweets you want to retrive max 200

> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2

Comment: This is not what was asked, the OP wants to get a list of all verified accounts