# How do I perform a Search Query to pull out results as Verified Twitter Accounts?

Tags: twitter

> I want to use the Twitter API on my website to provide links to
>   Verified Individual/Organization Twitter Profile on entering a search
>   query on my website.

Suppose, I enter "Rihanna",
then how do I pull and display the verified profile link of Rihanna as a result?

P.S.: A similar question **with entirely different context** was asked, and inadequately answered. Please do not mark as duplicate of [that question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890406/how-to-pull-the-list-of-verified-accounts-via-twitter-api)

---

---

Comment: There is no Twitter API that would provide this list of user accounts and links. You *can* use the premium Search APIs to search for Tweets posted by premium accounts, but there's no endpoint to query for a list of those verified accounts as a separate resource. (this is a fact, I work on the developer platform at Twitter)

Comment: @AndyPiper Thanks for letting me know. :) Is there any workaround? Anything? Any website/web service which is already doing it on its own other than Twitter?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.